# Plotting Quantile regression with full range in ggplot using facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression, quantile, quantreg

So I would like to plot entire full range quantile lines in full range when using `facet_wrap`. The code goes as follows:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(quantreg)

mtcars %>% 
  gather("variable", "value", -c(3, 10)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(value, disp)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color = factor(gear))) + 
  geom_quantile(quantiles = 0.5, 
                aes(group = factor(gear), color = factor(gear))) +
  facet_wrap(~variable, scales = "free")
#> [multiple warnings removed for clarity]
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-12-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

As can be seen regression lines don't have full range and I cannot solve this easily.

Comment: Related post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59184868/geom-quantile-full-range-in-ggplot2

Comment: One benefit to `ggplot` not extending the fitted lines by default, is that it clearly shows the extent of the (x-axis) data that the model was trained on. This can help highlight potential data gaps. Anything beyond the lines is extrapolation (which may or may not be fine).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feels over-engineered, but one approach would be to get the slope-intercept figures outside of ggplot and then plot them using `geom_abline`. A potential downside of this implementation is that it uses some jittering to prevent a "singular design matrix" error in `rq`, but this means that it would generate random slopes even for data with only one x value. To get around that, there's a step here to remove data from the slop calculation if it only has one value for that variable-gear combination.

```
mtcars %>% 
  gather("variable", "value", -c(3, 10)) -> mt_tidy

mt_tidy %>%
  # EDIT: Added section to remove data that only has one value for that
  #   variable and gear. 
  group_by(variable, gear) %>%
    mutate(distinct_values = n_distinct(value)) %>% 
    ungroup() %>%
    filter(distinct_values > 1) %>%
    select(-distinct_values) %>%

  nest_legacy(-c(variable, gear)) %>% 
  # the jittering here avoids the "Singular design matrix" error
  mutate(qtile = map(data, ~ rq(jitter(.x$disp) ~ jitter(.x$value), 
                                tau = 0.5)),
         tidied = map(qtile, broom::tidy)) %>%
  unnest_legacy(tidied) %>%
  select(gear:estimate) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = term, values_from = estimate) %>%
  select(gear, variable, 
         intercept = `(Intercept)`, 
         slope = `jitter(.x$value)`) -> qtl_lines

ggplot(mt_tidy, aes(value, disp, color = factor(gear))) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_abline(data = qtl_lines,
              aes(intercept = intercept, slope = slope,
                  color = factor(gear))) +
  facet_wrap(~variable, scales = "free")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer this approach seems to be pretty good, however It can be seen that eg. in am variable there is a random slope for factor 3, how would we solve it, so that the random slopes would not be here - One again thank you very much, I will try to play around with it a bit...

Comment: Edited to add a step to exclude data with only one value for that variable-gear combo.